# AWS SQS: Delay making available a message that failed to process

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Here's my scenario:

- I have an SQS queue which processes a number of tasks. Those tasks can, and often times do, fail. Their failure is common and somewhat expected.
- When a task fails, I want to retry it *after a certain amount of time*, and fail the item into a DLQ after a certain amount of retries. I do not want to retry immediately.

I have a worker EB app which processes these tasks. When it succeeds, I return 200 (and the task is successfully removed from the queue). When it fails I return 404, and the task is immediately returned to the queue (and, thus, immediately retried). This is not desired, I'd like to delay this failed item before it is retried.

Is it possible to do this with a combination of visibility timeouts and delay queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered my own question, turns out I was looking in the wrong place (SQS config options, not EB config options). The magic settings I was looking for is "error visibility timeout" in the EB config options, which allows you to control the amount of time a failed item has before returning to its queue.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this natively with SQS by calling ChangeMessageVisibility on a message you just failed to process and setting the VisibilityTimeout to whatever you want: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeMessageVisibility.html